# Check Home button is Pressed in Galaxy note

Tags: android

I have an app for Galaxy Note in which i have to check that "home/Center"  key is pressed. Is there any function for it like for when back button  there is a default function onBackPressed. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onUserLeaveHint(). when the user presses the Home key, `onUserLeaveHint()` will be called, but when an incoming phone call causes the in-call Activity to be automatically brought to the foreground, `onUserLeaveHint()` will not be called on the activity being interrupted

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no way to catch the home-key in android. Ideally it is not for developers. 
But you can do the following

1. onPause will be called if following events occur
   a. User Press Home Key
   b. User press back Key
   c. External interrupt like calls

   So since you can handle backpress, and listen on incoming call broadcast, then you can determine in the onPause method if it is due to home press.
2. Parse the logcat and then do necessary action in the background service